# Retrive records which are not referenced in other table, ActiveRecord query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

There are 2 tables : User and Teacher. Teacher.user_id is from User. So, how do I find in a single query, all the users who are not in teachers.

I meant something along the lines :

```
         User.not_in(Teacher.all)
```

Comment: Are you sure you don't mean "database table" instead of "database"?

Comment: Oops. That's what I meant. I'm a rails newbie. So, I use it all interchangably

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `where.not` query from `ActiveRecord` try something like below:

```
User.where.not(id: Teacher.pluck(:user_id).reject {|x| x.nil?})
```

Note: used `reject` method, in case you have nil values in some records.

Comment: Glad it worked but I would also suggest to consider other answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/38706214/2545197 as well.

Comment: it appears you were correct in assuming this was not rails 3 although in that event I would still take into consideration what we discussed on my post because if the teachers table gets too large the SQL will fail out since a query can only be so many characters long and the `Array` may cause it to exceed this. Simple solution is change the pluck version to `Teacher.where.not(id: nil).select(:user_id)` then it will execute the `reject` portion as a subquery instead.

Answer (score 1):

The other users seem to have neglected the rails 3 tag (since removed based on the approved answer. My answer left for posterity) : Please try this

```
User.where("id NOT IN (?)",Teacher.pluck(:user_id).join(","))
```

This will become `SELECT * FROM users WHERE id NOT IN (....)` (two queries one to get the `user_id` from teachers and another to get the `user`(s) not in that list) and may fail based on the size of teacher table.

Other option is an arel table:

```
users = User.arel_table
User.where(users[:id].not_in(Teacher.select(:user_id).where("user_id IS NOT NULL")))
```

This should produce a single query similar to

```
SELECT * FROM users 
WHERE id NOT IN ( SELECT user_id FROM teachers WHERE user_id IS NOT NULL)
```

(one query better performance) * syntax was not fully tested

Another single query option might be

```
User.joins("LEFT OUTER JOIN teachers ON teachers.user_id = users.id").
     where("teachers.user_id IS NULL")
```

Comment: Hey I completely agree with you views here, but isn't it still running two queries?

Comment: @Abhinay it does not require SQL to return to the program build an `Array` and then execute a second query as where as the `pluck` method will require this. Instead the whole query is executed on the SQL server and only the required result is returned. But technically you could see the sub query as a second query thus enter my third suggestion which truly is 1 query.

Comment: Got it, thanks for explaining. btw given the way user who has asked this question I doubt that he really meant rails-3 version. he did mentioned about being a newbie

Answer (score -1):

I think you should be able to do something like this

```
User.where.not(id: Teacher.ids)
```

Comment: This won't work, you should be passing `user_id` to it instead of `teacher_id`